# LTSpice fall time - rise time problem

Tags: ltspice

Why doesn't the inductor reach 12V in this circuit?
Default rise and fall time is 1ms.
This circuit does not work correctly.
When I set rise and fall time to 1n it works correctly.
Why is the circuit responding?
Can be parasitic capacitance?
As far as I know, firstly while the inductor is charging, it starts equal to the source voltage. Then it decreases over time. The problem is that the inductor voltage starts to decrease before it reaches the source voltage.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the time constant for that L R combination? How does that compare to your selected rise time?

Comment: Time constant is 0.5 second.I don't know how I compare.

Comment: "The problem is that the inductor voltage starts to decrease before it reaches the source voltage" - that is what should happen with your circuit. There is no parasitic capacitance in the model only a small amount of series resistance that you can change by editing the model.

Comment: In the second picture, when I set the rise and fall time to 1n or 1u, it reached 12V. This is the part I don't understand. How did this difference occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current through an inductor **cannot** change instantaneously. In your circuit, if \$I_L(0^-)=0\text{A} \$ then it must be that \$I_L(0^+)=0\text{A} \$.

If \$I_L(0^+)=0\text{A} \$, then certainly \$V_{R}(0^+)=0\text{V} \: \Rightarrow V_L(0^+)=V_{\text{source}}\$. So the voltage across the inductor is the same as voltage drop delivered by the source at \$t=0^+ \$.

In your first circuit, the rise time is too slow. Looking at it, I see that \$V_{\text{source}}(0^+)=V_L(0^+) =2\text{V}\$.

In your second circuit, the rise time is fast enough for the circuit to keep up with theory: \$V_{\text{source}}(0^+)=V_L(0^+)=12\text{V} \$

Can you see the difference? Approximating \$0^+ \approx 1\text{ns} \: \$ clearly shows why \$V_L(0^+) \$ would be different in your two cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you set rise and fall times to zero in LTspice, you do not get 0, for reasons that have to do with the inner workings of the solver and the desire to have it converge under default conditions.

Rather you get a default rise and fall time- from ltwiki:

> Default value: 10% of Ton or 10% of Tperiod-Ton whatever is smaller.
> You must specify Trise and Tfall if you want a certain value.

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage is dropping on the resistors and on the inductor, it’s a voltage divider , so the output voltage should never get to 12 volts.

As for the timing I see a rise and fall time in the  screenshot as it should be , the inductor is an energy storage element when current changes, that’s why the voltage across it changes when input voltage changes, and it’s zero volts when the source’s voltage is constant.

Comment: When I set 1n it reached 12V.You can see in second pic.

Comment: @bahadırgüven when you set it to 0 it isn’t actually zero , it’s the default which is more than 1n , which make the change in current slower compared than the 1n , which makes the inductor’s resistance lower and the voltage drop across it lower than the one on 1ns pluse .

Comment: I disagree.In the step response of a RL circuit in DC voltages the voltage of inductor becomes equal to the voltage of the battery at 0 , which is when the current in the circuit is 0.

Comment: Is this system related to dv/dt? Low dv/dt does not fill the parasitic capasitance of the circuit because less current flows.

Comment: See this:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KylJ2v1_c-o

Comment: @MissMulan I’m familiar with ngspice not ltspice so I don’t know what is step response , I suppose it’s the same as transient analysis. anyway , no it won’t get to 12v on dc voltage, you confuse it with RC circuit.   The output is on the inductor which acts as a wire when the current is constant (like DC) , the 12v will drop on the resistor.

Comment: Yes in its steady state the voltage of the inductor will be 0 , but at 0 seconds the voltage of the inductor is 12V

Comment: @Miss Mulan In the first picture, the inductor cannot go to 12V at 0 seconds.

Comment: In all the books it is said that the current rises up to V/R for the rl circuit. The inductor voltage starts from the source voltage and decreases. As the inductor voltage decreases, the resistor voltage increases. Am I wrong?

Comment: look o the simulation and tell me is it on exact 12 ? are you suggesting that the simulation is wrong and you are right ? and who -1 my answer? you both are trying so hard to prove that it is 12v at the tiny little almost non-existing time fraction of of a second at the beginning  , whatever , look to the simulation result ,it's a voltage divider.
I've explained enogh , the rest is on you.

Comment: I understand you, but I'm not asking this. I'm trying to understand the system that makes the inductor voltage rise to less voltage

Comment: @bahadırgüven  Think about it this way.  The slope of the voltage is related to the frequencies passing through the inductor.  The impedance of the inductor will change based on these frequencies.  The answer is saying you can never completely reach 12V because you can't have zero risetime, and therefore the magnitude of the inductor impedance can never completely be zero.  You can probably get extreme close, though, if you make the risetime `1f` (1 femtosecond).  Also, don't forget that inductors in LTspice have a default ESR of 1mohm (unless you right-click the inductor and set to zero).